# Prestashop and null fields in DB

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.5

I have a very simple piece of code :

```
$dropOrder = new DropOrder($dropOrderId);
$dropOrder->is_supplier_paid = $payValue;
$dropOrder->save();
```

It works and saves a 'is_supplier_paid' field value into the database. But it also does unexpected actions and fills all null valued fields with 0 values.

I try to save it like this :

```
$dropOrder->save(true);
```

But I still have the same strange behavior. I want to change one field only and don't touch the other ones.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Values are formated by **ObjectModel::formatValue()** before they are inserted / updated, based on the type of the field declared in your **$definition**.

You have to use **TYPE_NOTHING** to allow *NULL* values, it's the only way.

Take a look in *Configuration* class, with **id_shop** and **id_group_shop** fields.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Really helpful information. I've not found that nowhere. You saved my live.

Answer (score 0):

PrestaShop 1.7:

I ran into the same problem in PS 1.7 and set TYPE_NOTHING is not sufficient to resolve this issue. In my case i also needed to add `allow_null` to `true` in the field's definition:

```
'my_field' => ['type' => self::TYPE_NOTHING, 'allow_null' => true, 'value' => null]
```

(`'value' => null` is probably not necessary but suggested)